# Multiply 2D arrays ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? (Java)

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to write a method that multiplies two matrices together and returns a 2D array with the resulting product. For example, the first matrix is a 5 x 2, and the second is a 2 x 5. The resulting matrix should be a 5 x 5 matrix respectively.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static int[][] multiplyArrays(int[][] arrayA, int[][] arrayB) {
    int[][] arrayProduct = new int[arrayA.length][arrayB[0].length];

    for (int cRow = 0; cRow < arrayA.length; cRow++) {
       for (int dCol = 0; dCol < arrayB[0].length; dCol++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < arrayB[0].length; i++) {
             arrayProduct[cRow][dCol] += arrayA[cRow][i] * arrayB[i][dCol];

          }
       }
    }
}
```

Whenever I'm runnning this code, it keeps giving me an exception saying ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2?

What is wrong with my logic in the code?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT: The fixed version of this code would be

```
public static int[][] multiplyArrays(int[][] arrayA, int[][] arrayB) {
    int[][] arrayProduct = new int[arrayA.length][arrayB[0].length];

    for (int cRow = 0; cRow < arrayA.length; cRow++) {
       for (int dCol = 0; dCol < arrayB[0].length; dCol++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < arrayA[0].length; i++) {**
             arrayProduct[cRow][dCol] += arrayA[cRow][i] * arrayB[i][dCol];

          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner-most loop use

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayA[0].length; i++)
```

instead of

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayB[0].length; i++)
```

Comment: I must've been overlooking at my code way too much. Thanks so much for your help!